# How to get Type object from assembly DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have DLL compiled from UnityEngine(**Assembly-C-Sharp.dll**) i want to read the struct and type object the DLL from Win Application C# .Net. why i use this method not from UnityEngine app? because i want make the editor with compiled with win application. so, after that ill share it.
Example algorithm (in DLL) :

```
namespace project
    class a
    class b
    class c
```

Example in C# Win Project :

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.Load("project");
ass. (gettype/ getlist class etc //i dont know more about this.
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask : "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important!" . Also, what do you intend to do with the Type objects? If you do not have a compile time reference to the DLL you will need a huge amount of reflection to do most things.

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` **not** in `unityscript` which is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like language used in previous Unity versions and is long deprecated by now. You should rather use the tag `unity3d`

Comment: Your question is (probably) too broad as an SO question, but everything you need can be found in the [System.Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=net-5.0) namespace.

Comment: If you want to explore your c# assembly/objects/types, try dnSpy https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy